# Can't see SVGs (evil-icons) after packaging electron app

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm writing a desktop app with `electron` and `react` [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate)

So far all things work well, but the "finished" app does not show the icons.

I use the `react-evil-icons` package, which puts some vectors into the DOM and references them by something like:

```
<svg>
    <use xlinkHref='#ei-archive-icon' />
</svg>
```

I've already tried adding the `evil-icons` package to `webpack.config.base.js` `externals`

```
externals: [
  'evil-icons'
]
```

..but without success.

Comment: Did you require `evil-icons.css` ?

Comment: damn.. I wish every hickup would be that easy :)
It's only required in the `hot-dev-app.html`

Comment: btw. I don't think i's a nice solution to require it into the `head` by its own. Could you tell me how to build it with webpack?

Comment: If you use `less` preprocessor you can import `evil-icons.css` in base less file. Or you can make EvilIcons.js that will import both files (css and react component) and export back react component. In fact, I'm not sure which way is better.